# Prove:$a_n \geq \frac{1}{4} C_n^3$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

With an positive integer $n \geq 4$, put $a_n$ is the smallest number of subset ($S_j$) has $3$ elements from $S_n= ({1;2;3;...;n})$ that with all subsets have $4$ elements from $S_n$, put it is $S_t$ will have at least $1$ $S_t$ that have at least one $S_j$ inside it.

i) Find  $a_6$?

ii) Prove that with all positive integer $n \geq 4$ we have: $a_n \geq \frac{1}{4} C_n^3$.

In i), I will try to count and make the formula for $a_n$,

In $n=4$, we have: $S_n=(1;2;3;4)$

So $S_j=[(1;2;3);(1;2;4);(1;3;4);(2;3;4)]$

So the number for $a_4=4$

In $n=5$, we have $S_n=(1;2;3;4;5)$

So $S_j=[(1;2;3);(1;2;4)(1;2;5);(2;3;4);(2;3;5);(3;4;5)]$

With each $S_j$, we can add $2$ elements form $S_5$ into it, but some sets will be the same as each other, I stuck here and can't find an effective way to count without making the sets same.

Comment: Please include work and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: @VincentBatens I included it, thanks

Comment: I really don't understand what exactly you are asking. Is it asking to find the smallest set of subsets of $S_n$ such that the union of two of those subsets contains exactly 4  elements of $S_n$ and the smallest subset in that set has 3 elements? (This is probably wrong since your example for $n=5$ doesn't match this problem, but can you try to explain the problem from here, because this is my best attempt to understand what you are asking?)

Comment: yes, sorry for my english

Comment: No problem. But if that's the problem, why is $a_4=2$ not the solution since you can have $\{(1;2;3);(1;2;4)\}$

Comment: I am not sure, but your definition of $a_n$ doesn't seem to be what Vincent proposed, but rather: $a_n$ is the smallest number $r$ such that there exist subsets $A_1,\dots,A_r\subset\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ of cardinal $3$ such that every subset $B\subset\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ of cardinal $4$ contains at least one $A_k.$ If so, $a_4=1.$

Comment: Ah that makes more sense indeed.

Comment: Uhm I think that I can understand the problem like this, let $S_n=(1;2;...;n)$. Then for every $S_t$ have 4 elements from $S_n$ will contain at least 1 $S_j$. $S_j$ is the set which has 3 elements from $S_n$. And it asked for the number smallest of $S_j$?

Comment: @VincentBatens, I think the problem is to find all $S_j$, example like this: $S_{j1}= (x_1,x_2,x_3)$. Then we just need to add some $x_t \in S_n$. But then some set $S_{jp}$ when add some $x_t \in S_n$ will be the same as each other